# Is there a #define associated with the SubSystem

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm creating main with a macro and need to be able to check the selected SubSystem at compile time, /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS or /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE, in order to generate the appropriate main function.  Is there a #define I can check that accomplishes this?

Comment: You should not generate a main function, because generating it is worthless to yourself and a hindrance to others. I.e. it has negative utility to do it. But if you do, like, hell-bent on generating a `main` function, then *generate a standard `main`*. It works fine no matter subsystem of the build. Note: with Microsoft tools, which are a bit challenged in this department, set linker option `/entry:mainCRTStartup` unless you're doing an MFC application, in which case you're up against the problem of others (namely Microsoft) having had the same Really Bad Idea™ of taking over `main`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to make things easy for users of your library (or whatever it is), you could just generate both `WinMain` and `main` from your macro. The linker by default sets console apps to start at `main`, and win32 apps to start at `WinMain`. The other "main" function will be ignored.

(Presumably the rest of the code doesn't use any of the main function arguments (`argc`, `argv`, `hInstance`, etc.), if it's to work with both.)

The `_CONSOLE` define could be used, but it doesn't appear automatically; you have to add it manually in to the project properties. The selection of startup symbol, on the other hand, is automatic. So just providing both functions, and letting the linker pick, might make life easier, because the project creator doesn't have to set anything up, and can indeed switch from windows to console app (possibly even per-configuration) without having to do anything.

Comment: "The linker by default sets console apps to start at main, and win32 apps to start at WinMain". No. (1) That's the Microsoft linker, not e.g. the MinGW linker. And (2) execution doesn't start at these functions.

Answer (score 15):

`_CONSOLE` should do the trick for you.
Also you can select the subsystem using `#pragma comment( linker, "/subsystem:windows" )` or `#pragma comment( linker, "/subsystem:console" )` if you really want to go this route.

Comment: This is definitely the better answer as it directly answers the original question of manually specifying the system vs. letting the linker determine it (or changing project settings).

Comment: How/where does `_CONSOLE` get defined?

Comment: @jww You have to pass it as a compiler option `/D "_CONSOLE"`.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how it really works.  You have to write dramatically different code in a console app vs a native Windows app.  In a console app, you use printf or cout to produce output, don't have much if any use for a mouse.  A native Windows app requires a message loop and creating a window with a window procedure that detects the WM_PAINT message to update the window.  Etcetera.

But you can write code that does both.  Just write both a main() and a WinMain() function, the CRT automatically calls the correct one.

Comment: While the statements you made are true, they don't tell the whole story. It is possible to write an application that functions with or without the console subsystem via a few small tweeks. Typically this would be a windowless application (or it may simply call MessageBox) and have no UI thread. The standard pipes are available to non-console apps as well, though of course their output would not be seen unless redirected.

Comment: Indeed. All my apps are console apps in the debug build, and it's basically 6 lines of extra code: a main function that does `return WinMain(0,0,0,0)`, all inside `#ifdef _CONSOLE`. You don't even really need the `#ifdef`.